# Created blank theme for REST API, featured image not appearing on admin side

Tags: theme-development, post-thumbnails

I have a blank theme purely to redirect to my custom front-end.  I created a `functions.php` and put `add_theme_support()` inside it and to no avail.

index.php:

```
<meta content="0; URL='https://headless-cms.test''" http-equiv"refresh">

<!-- just in case the meta tag is not read properly, here is plan B: a JS redirect -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.location = 'https://headless-cms.test';
</script>
```

functions.php

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'headless_theme_setup' );
function headless_theme_setup() {
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails');
}

// Also tried these and still didn't show

//add_theme_support('post-thumbnails', array(
//    'post',
//    'page',
//));
//add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

I refreshed the admin panel and checked under `screen options` and did not see it.  I'm using WP 5.0.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the symbolic link between my Wordpress install in my public/ and build/ directory was out of sync.  I forgot to run `yarn build` after adding the function.

My directory structure is like this:

```
site/
|__build/
   |_wp/
|
|__/src/
   |_wp/
```

So the changes I made in src/ were not being compiled off the build.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me,

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'headless_theme_setup' );
function headless_theme_setup() {
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails',  array( 'post' ) );
}
```

[image]

WordPress version 5.0.2